# insmod command throwing WARNING message while inserting kernel module

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, kernel-module, perf, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am testing an kernel module which creates perf events on every core and count the total number of *L2D_CACHE_REFILL*.

```
System details: NVIDIA Jetson nano, OS: Ubuntu  18.04.6 LTS, Kernel: 4.9.255, L4T: 32.7.3, Jetpack: 4.6.3
```

When I try to insert this module using `insmod` command, i get WARNING message in kernel log file. The screenshot of `dmesg` command is shown below:
[image]

This warning states that at line no. 199, the function `armpmu_start()` is throwing an warning.

I tried checking the kernel source code. The kernel code snippet for `armpmu_start` function from `drivers/perf/arm_pmu` file is as below:

[image]

Also when I try to remove the module with `rmmod` command my jetson nano board is restarting.

Here are the few perf APIs the kernel module is using:

1. Creating attributes structure of the perf event

> ```
>  struct perf_event_attr sched_perf_hw_attr = {
>               .type       = PERF_TYPE_RAW,
>               .config     = 0x17,
>               .size       = sizeof (struct perf_event_attr),
>               .pinned     = 1,
>               .disabled   = 1,
>               .exclude_kernel = 1,
>               .sample_period  = budget
>           };
> ```

2. Creating perf event with `event_overflow_callback` function

   > event = perf_event_create_kernel_counter (&sched_perf_hw_attr,
   > cpu,
   > NULL,
   > event_overflow_callback,
   > NULL
   > );
3. Code to start the counter

> ```
> perf_event_enable (event);
> event->pmu->add (event, PERF_EF_START);
> ```

4. Code to stop the counter

> event->pmu->stop (event, PERF_EF_UPDATE);
> event->pmu->del(event,0);

5. In the `event_overflow_callback` function following activities are performed.

Stopping counter

> event->pmu->stop (event, PERF_EF_UPDATE);

Enable performance counter

> event->pmu->start (event, PERF_EF_RELOAD);

Is the last statement creating an issue? I tried setting the parameters to `PERF_EF_UPDATE/ PF_EF_START` in the `start()` function. But still getting the same warning.

Any help in diagnosing the issue is highly appreciated.
I am new to Linux kernel module. Kindly suggest a methods of debugging Linux kernel modules on embedded devices like Nvidia jetson boards. That will help me in gaining knowledge.

Comment: Same question is also asked on NVIDIA developer forum and can be found at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/issue-in-inserting-a-kernel-module-for-performance-counters-on-jetson-nano/252051